# Improvement to 'grep -h "BSD process name" /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/* | sort | uniq -c'

Tags: macos, terminal, crash

To track down the culprit for the frequent crashes of Lion, I ran:

```
grep -h "BSD process name" /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/* | sort | uniq -c
```

which produced:

```
   1 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Finder
   1 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: PluginProcess
   1 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: PubSubAgent
   1 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: SystemUIServer
   2 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WebProcess
   1 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
   1 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: coreaudiod
   8 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
   2 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: launchd
   1 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: mds
   1 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: mdworker
```

but this list seems to be far from complete for the number of crashes I had over the past few days -- during startup, shutdown, and in-between (and /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports contains 17 days worth of crash reports). What can one run in the terminal to produce a more comprehensive list of OS X crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the reports in my own .../DiagnosticReports directory, I see lots of entries that don't have a "BSD process name" section.  In fact, I don't have that line in any of the files in DiagnosticReports.

I think you need to grep on a different term, perhaps "^Process:"

```
grep -h "^Process:" /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/* | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: This is not quite right. It captures only crashes of 'powerd' (whatever that is.. power daemon?). It does not capture the crashes resulting from the one program in Lion most often responsible for a crash: kernel_task.