# Troubleshot rebooting Mac mini server

Tags: macos, mac, osx-server

I have a Mac mini running 10.13.6 as a server.

- Time Machine
- homebridge
- File Server
- Content caching
- Netinstall
- Xcode
- running VMware Fusion with Linux guest system

Since a few weeks, the whole system starts at  random moments.

What would be a way to troubleshot this?

Comment: Take a look at the logs (using the console application). Everything else depends on what you find here and cannot be generally answered.

Comment: I'm not sure where to look exactly. In the console app, I just see the events till the start of the machine. Can you point me, where I should start to look?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to get into the console app / system log and trace the shutdown cause and timing of the restarts. Then you would look to see if there are hangs or crashes in /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports prior to those events.

- [The reason for Previous shutdown cause: -128](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212506/the-reason-for-previous-shutdown-cause-128)
- [Shutdown cause: -104](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179648/shutdown-cause-104)

Depending on your interest in scripting shell to collect matches from log files, here’s an example of using those log files to find events like needles in a very large, long and confusing haystack.

- [Improvement to 'grep -h "BSD process name" /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/* | sort | uniq -c'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29279/improvement-to-grep-h-bsd-process-name-library-logs-diagnosticreports-s)

Most likely, you will see a pattern (or see there is no pattern once you get 25 restarts logged and cataloged) and can remove the hardware, software or look into what is the logged reason.